# Mutex locking when shared memory is only read

Tags: c++, c, multithreading

Is my impression correct that if shared memory between threads is only read and never written, by any of the threads, mutex protection is unneccessary?

It's because wherever a thread is preempted, it can always take off again when rescheduled, and the memory contents would not have changed.

Comment: This [previous SO](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15744475/1079907) might answer it.

Comment: @SunEric: It does not mention the answer to my question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you're right, multiple threads reading the same variable do not introduce a race.

Comment: @KerrekSB Lol, pun was not intended)

Comment: They can't race with each other, but if anything is writing to the memory, you need some kind of barrier between the write and reads to avoid data races.

Comment: In which case the typical mechanism used is the [readers-writer lock](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Readers%E2%80%93writer_lock).

Answer (score 3):

Both C++11 and C11 define a *data race* to be access to a memory location by more than one execution context without ordering where at least one of the accesses is a write. If you have no writes, you have no races.